# Reading I2C data from SW6106 register

Tags: serial, power, i2c, battery

I am using the SW6106 powerbank IC as an I2C but no matter what I have tried I couldn't read something other than "FF".

[Datasheet for the IC.](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/0/05/SW6106_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf)

Timing diagram for reading data:
[image: Read Timing Diagram]

Timing diagram for writing data:
[image: Write Timing Diagram]

The code I use:

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte ADDRESS_SLAVE = 0x3C; 
byte REGISTER_XY = 0xB0;
byte READ_LENGTH = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000); // set I2C 'full-speed'

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_SLAVE);  
  Wire.write(REGISTER_XY);  // set register for read
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop() {
   Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_SLAVE,READ_LENGTH); 
   byte buff[READ_LENGTH];    
   Wire.readBytes(buff, READ_LENGTH);
   for (int i = 0; i < READ_LENGTH; i++) {
     Serial.println(buff[i], HEX);
   }
   Serial.println();
   delay(1000);
}
```

Serial monitor output:
[image: Serial Monitor]

I really couldn't understand anything from that timing diagram and couldn't read anything from the IC. I'd appreciate any help.

Edit:
I edited the code a little bit to see what Wire.endTransmission(); returns.

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte ADDRESS_SLAVE = 0x3C; 
byte REGISTER_XY = 0xB0;
byte READ_LENGTH = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000); // set I2C 'full-speed'
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_SLAVE);  
  Wire.write(REGISTER_XY);  // set register for read
  int x = Wire.endTransmission();
  Serial.println(x, DEC);
  delay(200);
}
```

And it retruns the following:
[image: endTransmission]

I really don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the I2C scanner to check it's on the right address? Sometimes the quoted address in datasheets is the 7-bit address and sometimes the 8-bit address.

Comment: @Majenko Yes, I have tried it and I can confirm it's on the right address.

Comment: The way that I2C works on that chip, looking at the diagrams, is perfectly normal. Maybe if you move the write (register select) into the loop to just before the read?

Comment: Is pin `LED4/I2C` connected to ground?

Comment: You ignore both the return values from `Wire.endTransmission()` and `Wire.requestFrom()`. Please output them to the Serial monitor for debugging. `Wire.endTransmission()` returns a status code and `Wire.requestFrom()` returns the number of bytes actually read.

Comment: @chrisl I edited the code to see what `Wire.endTransmission()` returns, and it returns a 0 or 3. I edited the post and added the code with a screenshot of the serial monitor.

Comment: Check the clock of the power bank ic

Comment: @AderNawfal the datasheet say it is 100/400K. I tried both of them and the results are same for both of them.

Comment: What the diagram shows is a write to slave address `0x3C` with the value `0xB0`, then a read 1-byte request for address `0x3C`. Can you try this code? https://hastebin.com/wuxuxulito.cpp

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I tried your code and it returns the following `I2C write ret: 0
I2C slave sent us 8 bytes
0`. I really don't know why the ic returns 0.

Comment: So the I2C write goes through without any errors (was ACKed on both address and data), and the read returns a whopping 8 bytes (?) but then only 1 byte with content `0x00`? What's supposed to be returned as data? I can just see 1 byte, but not the meaning. You can also try to remove the `Serial.println()` except for the one that print the bytes, and some dividor between.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Oh, I am really sorry, I was just editing the code to see the other bytes if I could get anything. The original code returns `I2C write ret: 0
I2C slave sent us 1 bytes
0
`. So It doesn't returns 8 bytes. And I don't know what it should return because the datasheet doesn't specifies anything about the data.

Comment: Well so it *does* correctly see the data I assume. If you have a logic analyzer you can double-check the data trace. Now the translated datasheet (http://ismartware.com/enet_upload/file/20181214/20181214101104_63565.pdf) really doesn't say much more, but it does show that "IRQ" should be connected also. Maybe certain events trigger an IRQ pulse and you're supposed to read the I2C register? But then why are you allowed to write to it? Is it for the LEDs or input? The datasheet gives 0 information about this and withouth that I don't know what you further want to do with this chip..

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I found this chip on a cheap qc3.0 supported powerbank pcb and when I checked the datasheet I saw that it supports i2c. So I thought to myself maybe I could get some verbose data about the current and voltage output and maybe a battery gauge. But the datasheet is really poor documented. I hope I can get something useful out of it

Comment: Next best thing would be to find out a contact email of the chip manufacturer and request details.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is very old, but I was able to get the register map from the manufacturer, Ismartware. [Here's a link to the datapack](https://archive.org/details/sw-6106-schematic-release-sch-006-v-2.2) for anyone else that may end up here while searching for the same thing.